# Distinct Count Totals Incorrect When new Column (Dimension) Added

Tags: sql, count, azure-sql-database, aggregation, distinct-values

I have a query where I need to count a field to come up with a value for 'delivery stops' as shown below:

```sql
SELECT 
    [EAR_START_DTTM_H],
    cast(year([EAR_START_DTTM_H]) as varchar(4))  +  right('0' + cast(month([EAR_START_DTTM_H]) as varchar(2)), 2) as calmonth,
    count(distinct[RATING_GROUP]) as delivery_stops
FROM [raw_abdc_operations].[sapbw_emanifest_data]
  where [EAR_START_DTTM_H] >= '2022-05-01' and [EAR_START_DTTM_H] < '2022-05-04' and org = '018'
  group by [EAR_START_DTTM_H]
  order by [EAR_START_DTTM_H]
```

[SQL 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzZFa.png)

RESULTS 1:

```
EAR_START_DTTM_H    calmonth delivery_stops
2022-05-02T00:00:00 202205   1656
2022-05-03T00:00:00 202205   1688
                    **Total  3,344**
```

[Result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8rEn.png)

However, when I add another dimension or column (ie. Prod Cat), the total is now way over-stated and the field is listed multiple times:

```sql
SELECT 
    [EAR_START_DTTM_H],
    cast(year([EAR_START_DTTM_H]) as varchar(4))  +  right('0' + cast(month([EAR_START_DTTM_H]) as varchar(2)), 2) as calmonth,
    [PRODUCT_CAT],
    count(distinct[RATING_GROUP]) as delivery_stops
FROM [raw_abdc_operations].[sapbw_emanifest_data]
  where [EAR_START_DTTM_H] >= '2022-05-01' and [EAR_START_DTTM_H] < '2022-05-04' and org = '018'
  group by [EAR_START_DTTM_H],[PRODUCT_CAT]
  order by [EAR_START_DTTM_H],[PRODUCT_CAT]
```

[SQL 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYdBN.png)

RESULTS 2:

```
EAR_START_DTTM_H    calmonth PRODUCT_CAT delivery_stops
2022-05-02T00:00:00 202205   COLTOTL     1082
2022-05-02T00:00:00 202205   COLTOTS     742
2022-05-02T00:00:00 202205   DRPPKG      1031
2022-05-02T00:00:00 202205   LTOTE       1346
2022-05-02T00:00:00 202205   NC_CS       71
2022-05-02T00:00:00 202205   STOTE       1618
2022-05-03T00:00:00 202205   COLTOTL     1072
2022-05-03T00:00:00 202205   COLTOTS     816
2022-05-03T00:00:00 202205   DRPPKG      998
2022-05-03T00:00:00 202205   LTOTE       1392
2022-05-03T00:00:00 202205   NC_CS       69
2022-05-03T00:00:00 202205   STOTE       1641
                                **Total  11,878**
```

[Result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8CRz.png)

Why are my results being blown up and seemingly double-triple counted?  What am I missing here? Any help would be much appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: The results are correct. You can't sum the total of a distinct and expect to get the same value from another with a different scope.

Comment: It's not correct in that I would expect the daily grand total to remain the same regardless of which columns / dimensions are added. How can this be coded appropriately?

Comment: It *is* correct, @A.cook . Imagine you have a table with 1 million rows, one column will 1 million different values and the other with the same value. If you do a `COUNT(DISTINCT)` without a `GROUP BY` you would get `1` and 1,000,000. If you then added a `GROUP BY` on the column that differs you would get 1,000,000 rows with 1 and 1 in *both* columns. Both answers are correct. It is your understanding that is wrong.

Comment: @Larnu-- you are not helping and really not answering the question except to tell me that my understanding is wrong.  The said total for the dates in question should be 3,344.  How can I retain that total for each day when I add in other dimensions? Should I sum the distinct count totals, do I need to put that base result in a temp table 1st before introducing other columns, do I need to partition the date? Should I convert the counts 1st to a numerical data type so I can sum the totals correctly for each day? Is there like a FOREACH function in SQL?

Comment: If you want to retain the same totals use `COUNT` *not* `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't `COUNT (DISTINCT)` the problem is your understanding. You *cannot* count distinct values and expect the *same* results for different grouping sets.

Take this overly simplified example:

| Grouping | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 1 | def |
| 2 | def |
| 2 | abc |

Now take the following query:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Value) AS DistinctValues
FROM dbo.SampleData;
```

This returns returns the following:

| DistinctValues |
| --- |
| 2 |

This is *correct*; there are **two** distinct values in the column `Value`; `'abc'` and `'def'`.

Now lets do the following query:

```sql
SELECT Grouping,
       COUNT(DISTINCT Value) AS DistinctValues
FROM dbo.SampleData
GROUP BY Grouping;
```

This returns the following result:

| Grouping | DistinctValues |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |

This too is **correct**; for each distinct value of `Grouping` there are 2 `DISTINCT` values for `Value` (`'abc'` and `'def'`again).

---

TL;DR: The `SUM` of a `COUNT(DISTINCT)` for one grouping does *not* equal the `SUM` of a `COUNT(DISTINCT)` for another grouping set. If you want a consistent count, use `COUNT`.